# Invoke Netezza Stored Procedure From SAS

Tags: sas, ssas, netezza

Is it possible to invoke a Netezza Stored procedure from SAS?If Yes, how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Netezza, but this is how I invoke an Oracle STP from SAS:

```
proc sql noprint;
         connect to oracle(user="&user"
         orapw="&passord"  path="&path"
         );
execute(
begin &schema..dvh_portal_pkg.schedule_upd( %str(%'&_METAUSER%'),&Schedule_id); end;
)by Oracle;
disconnect from Oracle;
quit;
```